# How to get Rid of this Nan?

Tags: javascript

I am building a dice with only Html and Javascript. I want the result of the two randomly generated number (addtion).
How can I get the Result as the sum of the both number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dice</title>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;color:lime;font-size:300%">Dice</h1>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    <h1 style="color: red;text-align:center;font-size:250%">You Have Got:</h1>
    <h1 style="color:gold;text-align:center;font-size:300%"><script type="text/javascript">
        var num1 = document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
        
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        var nu,2 = document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
        
        document.write("<br/>");

        num1 = parseFloat(num1);
        num2 = parseFloat(num2
);
  
        document.write("<br/>");

        document.write("Result:");

        document.write(dice1 + dice2);
     </script></h1>
    <button onClick="window.location.reload();" style="font-size:200%; margin:auto;display:block;background-color:black;color:cyan">Roll Again</button>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black">
</body>
</html>
```

So if I run this program.
I get the result as NaN.
I have tried

```
parseInt();
parseFloat();
```

[Here is the Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysk0a.png)

Comment: document write returns `undefined`

Comment: `var nu,2` looks like a typo, please correct this.

Comment: `dice1`/`dice2` have never been defined. Did you mean `num1`/`num2`?

Comment: Did you try Number(); instead of parseInt or parseFloat?

Comment: Yes i have tried Number()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just store the numbers as separate variables, so you don't have to convert when them before adding.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dice</title>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;color:lime;font-size:300%">Dice</h1>
  <hr />
  <br />
  <h1 style="color: red;text-align:center;font-size:250%">You Have Got:</h1>
  <h1 style="color:gold;text-align:center;font-size:300%">
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
      document.write(num1);

      document.write("<br/>");
      document.write("<br/>");

      var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
      document.write(num2);

      document.write("<br/>");

      //num1 = parseFloat(num1);
      //num2 = parseFloat(num2);

      document.write("<br/>");

      document.write("Result:");

      document.write(num1 + num2);
    </script>
  </h1>
  <button onClick="window.location.reload();"
    style="font-size:200%; margin:auto;display:block;background-color:black;color:cyan">Roll Again</button>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black">
</body>

</html>
```